# How can I improve my code to avoid GC overhead limit error?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm getting this error message:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

at catch block of this code:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) 
    {
        System.out.println("Starting try block");
        
        String line;
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        int rowIndex = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
            String[] tokens = line.split("[|]");
            for(int iToken = 0; iToken < tokens.length; iToken++) 
            {
                cell = row.createCell(iToken);
                cell.setCellValue(tokens[iToken]);
            }
            rowIndex++;
        }
    } 
    catch(Throwable e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The file I'm reading is large txt file (~90000KB).
After increasing VM memory to 2048K at run time I stopped getting HeapSize error but started getting GC error.
How can I modify the code to avoid the GC error?

Comment: Where are your `Cell` and `Row` classes coming from?

Comment: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel

Comment: POI’s XLSX code has far higher overhead than its XLS code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that `Sheet`, `Row` and `Cell` are classes from some Java spreadsheet API.

Here's the bad news.

The problem is that your code is building a large data structure that represents the spreadsheet in memory, and then writing it to a file.  Apparently the data structure is larger than can be accommodated by your JVM's heap.

The second problem is that if you continue to use the aforementioned API *in this way*, you won't be able to reduce the memory utilization.

There are a few ways to address this:

1. Increase the heap size, and keep increasing it until you don't get OOMEs.  If that means you need a machine with more RAM to run your application, get one.
2. If the API that you are using has a *streaming* mode for writing the data, use that.  Or look for an alternative to this API that supports streaming.
3. Maybe there is a non-streaming spreadsheet API that uses less memory than the one you are currently using.  (See @Holger's comment.)
4. Don't generate a spreadsheet.  Spreadsheets are (IMO) an inefficient way of representing data.  Instead, output the data as a CSV file, a JSON file, an XML file or any other format that can easily be streamed.
5. If the "business types" insist on spreadsheets, you could maybe output the data as a CSV file and then use an external tool to create the spreadsheet from the CSV file.

---

The streaming version of POI is described [here](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying different things. When trying the POI streaming version I got error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (1048576) outside allowable range (0..1048575)

Comment: According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), a worksheet is limited to 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen I switched to SXSSF and succeeded in writting the file